Telegram webapp screen size
I would like to know if the screen size of the Telegram mini app is fixed on the PC (Mac/Windows) or mobile (iOS/Android) versions.
I have noticed that during development, some people's display heights vary significantly. I want to know if this height is not fixed or if it is due to differences in devices.

Screen size vary from a device to another, I assume that you mean aspect ratio. For Mobile it's usually 9:16.

No, it is not, I realized this when I looked at the viewport on the iPhone XR, iPhone 14 Pro Max and iPhone 15. There is a different viewport everywhere, the only solution, in my opinion, is to disable scaling and use media queries.
UPD. I looked at the viewport on different devices and asked gpt to estimate the rest of the devices. In general here is the table



Device
Regular viewport
Approximate viewport in TG Mini App




iPhone 11
414px
375px


iPhone 11 Pro
375px
340px


iPhone 11 Pro Max
414px
375px


iPhone 12
390px
350px


iPhone 12 Mini
360px
330px


iPhone 12 Pro
390px
350px


iPhone 12 Pro Max
428px
390px


iPhone 13
390px
350px


iPhone 13 Mini
360px
330px


iPhone 13 Pro
390px
350px


iPhone 13 Pro Max
428px
390px


iPhone 14
390px
350px


iPhone 14 Plus
428px
390px


iPhone 14 Pro
393px
340px


iPhone 14 Pro Max
430px
390px


iPhone 15
393px
320px


iPhone 15 Plus
430px
390px


iPhone 15 Pro
393px
320px


iPhone 15 Pro Max
430px
390px


iPhone 16
450px
400px





/* iPhone 15 */
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 340px) {
    html {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
  
  /* iPhone 12 Mini, 13 */
  @media (min-width: 330px) and (max-width: 350px) {
    html {
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  }
  
  /* iPhone 11 Pro */
  @media (min-width: 340px) and (max-width: 375px) {
    html {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
  
  /* iPhone 12, 13, 14 */
  @media (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 390px) {
    html {
      font-size: 15px;
    }
  }
  
  /* iPhone 12 Pro Max, 14 Pro */
  @media (min-width: 390px) and (max-width: 430px) {
    html {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  }
  
  /* iPhone 15 Pro, 16 */
  @media (min-width: 400px) {
    html {
      font-size: 17px;
    }
  }



